# session_destroy not unsetting the session_id

Tags: php, session, sessionid

I am working on an online ticket booking systems where after making successful booking(after payment) I want to clear the session id. But the thing is I am not able to clear it although I have used `session_destroy()` to destroy the session.

NB: I have echoed the session_id to check if its reset or not.

URL: http://7sisters.in/7sislabs/

```
function book_final_tickets()
{

    //var_dump($_SESSION);
    $session_id = session_id();


    $sql = "
        UPDATE
            tbl_seat_book
        SET
            final_book = 'Y'
        WHERE
            session_id = '$session_id'
    ";


    //session_unset();

    if($r = $this->db->executeQuery($sql)){
        if(session_destroy()){
            unset($session_id); 
            echo 'Booking successfull';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your query is executed and the echo statement is printed?

Comment: ya...but I want to destroy the session after booking the tickets successfully .

Comment: If your echo statement is printed then your session should have been destroyed. Trying to debug why that can happen.

Comment: The echo shows same session_id , although it is destroyed (after successful booking)

Comment: Try using `session_unset()`. Also, try calling `session_start()` before `session_destroy()`.

Comment: Try using this order of functions: session_start(), session_unset(); , session_destroy(); , $_SESSION = array();

Comment: To make sure I destroy a session, I use `session_regenerate_id(true);` before `session_destroy()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `session_id` before `session_start`, and set `session_id` manually .

**Example 1: same session_id will be used**

```
<?php
session_start();

echo session_id(); //4ef975b277b52

session_destroy();

session_start();

echo session_id();  //4ef975b277b52
?>
```

**Example 2: set `session_id` manually (called before `session_start()`)**

```
<?php
session_id(uniqid()); 
session_start();

echo session_id(); //4ef975d3d52f5  (A)

session_destroy();


session_id(uniqid());
session_start();

echo session_id();  //4ef975d3b3399 (B)
?>
```

(A) != (B), so you can set session_id manually, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php for more information.

**Another solution**, dont use session_id() , just create new session array:

```
<?php
$_SESSION['booked'] = false;

if($r = $this->db->executeQuery($sql))
{
    $_SESSION['booked'] = true;
    echo 'Booking successfull';
}
?>
```

Comment: Setting a session ID manually with `session_id(uniqid());` is a bad idea. `uniqid()` isn't very random as it's timestamp based. Letting PHP handle generation of `session_id` automatically with `session_regenerate_id()` is much better, since then you can use a better entropy source (e.g. `ini_set('session.entropy_file', '/dev/urandom');`).

Comment: Rich, `session_regenerate_id()` has its own problems, even [its own doc page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php) discourages using it. However, one could still use `session_id(session_create_id())` to let PHP do its job, at least for the ID-generation part. (To fix the reliability issue itself, there's more to do, unfortunately. See the doc page.)

Answer (score 14):

`session_destroy()` alone won't remove the client-side cookie, so the next time the user visits, they'll still have the same session id set (but their server-side session info will have been destroyed).

From the docs (emphasis mine):

> session_destroy() destroys all of the data associated with the current
>   session. It does not unset any of the global variables associated with
>   the session, or unset the session cookie. ... In order to kill the
>   session altogether, like to log the user out, **the session id must also
>   be unset**. If a cookie is used to propagate the session id (default
>   behavior), then the session cookie must be deleted.

You can use [`session_regenerate_id(true)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php) to generate a new session ID and delete the old one. Note that this will keep all of the information in `$_SESSION` as part of the new session ID, so you still need to use `session_destroy` if you want to clear the session info and start fresh.

e.g.

```
<?php
    session_start();    
    $_SESSION['blah'] = true;

    var_dump(session_id()); // q4ufhl29bg63jbhr8nsjp665b1
    var_dump($_SESSION);    // blah = true

    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    setcookie("PHPSESSID", "", 1); // See note below
    session_start();
    session_regenerate_id(true);

    var_dump(session_id()); // gigtleqddo84l8cm15qe4il3q3
    var_dump($_SESSION);    // (empty)
?>
```

and the headers will show the session ID changing on the client-side:

> **Request Header**
>   Cookie:PHPSESSID=q4ufhl29bg63jbhr8nsjp665b1
>   **Response Header**
>   Set-Cookie:PHPSESSID=deleted; expires=Mon, 27-Dec-2010 16:47:57 GMT
>   PHPSESSID=gigtleqddo84l8cm15qe4il3q3; path=/

*(You can get away without the `setcookie()` call here, since you're creating a new session anyway, so the cookie will be overwritten by the new ID, but it's good practice to explicitly destroy the old cookie).*

Answer (score 4):

After destroying the session with session_destroy(), this worked for me:

setcookie('PHPSESSID',"",time()-3600,'/');

The key for me was setting the path to '/'.  That was the only way to really destroy the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
unset($session_id);
session_destroy();
```

Comment: I don't think $session_id is the problem here... it is too obvious. I think the cookie whitch holds the session id is still there, after session_destroy();

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`session_destroy();`

I'd rather do only a

`session_regenerate_id(true);`

and you will get a new session_id